# Matrix equation $2x(t)^T Ax(t) = x(t) ^T (A + A^T )x(t)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I found this equation online [here](http://stanford.edu/class/ee363/hw/hw6sol.pdf) and it seems false. can anyone please approve or disapprove ?
$$
2x(t)^T Ax(t) = x(t)^T(A + A^T)x(t)
$$

$A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $x(t)$ is a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: While the question is motivated by a differential equations context, that context is entirely irrelevant to the question as posed. So I've removed the diff-eq tag.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x^TAx$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix, $x^TAx=(x^TAx)^T=x^TA^Tx$. Therefore,

$$2x^TAx=x^TAx+x^TAx=x^TAx+x^TA^Tx=x^T(A+A^T)x. $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $x^TAx$ is a $1 \times 1$ matrix, i.e. a real number.  It follows that
$$
x^TAx = (x^TAx)^T = x^TA^Tx
$$

Comment: @user2129387 it sure is!  The sizes of the matrices being multiplied are $1 \times n$, $n \times n$, $n \times 1$.

Comment: oh you meant the whole expression

Comment: I mean, that is what I wrote

Answer (score 0):

Hint: By the definition of matrix multiplication, $$x^T A y = \sum_{ij}x_i A_{ij}y_j=\sum_{ij}y_j (A^T)_{ji}x_i=y^T A^T x$$ for any vectors $x,y$ and matrix $A$ of proper size. Consider the case of $y=x$.